# Cleaning up IndexedDB Object stores

Tags: indexeddb

I am implementing the use of IndexedDB storage in my webapp (Chrome only) which stores a sequence of records along the lines of

```
{raw:"string",id:"string",dayUsed:number}
```

where

1. id - is the unique string identifying the object (used as the indexedDB objectstore key
2. dayUsed - records the last day (since Date(2013,11,10)) that the object was used.

As the app is used the number of records in this store will grow.  I want to keep tabs on what is happening in this object store with a view to pruning it when

1. The number of records in the store exceeeds a preset threshold
2. There are records in the store with a dayUsed value exceeding a preset threshold

I have followed the MDN tutorial (which b.t.w has a few small bits of misinformation) and implemented most of what I need but the record pruning bit still seems unclear.

The core methods offered by IndexedDB are quite limited.  For instance, even getting the total number of records is not just a matter of issuing a one-liner.  Whilst the app is running I could from time-to-time run a cleanup routine that goes through the whole object store and deletes entries with dayUsed breahces.  However, given that my objectstore could well have several hundred entries this could be a lengthy operation that slows down the app.  Where then?  Spawn a webworker to do the job?

This is starting to look more complicated than I had envisaged.  To my question - are there high level wrappers that provide a SQL like interface to IndexedDB stores that can handle all such tasks well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my library https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/wiki/Home

The trick is you just use key to count daily use withiut storing anything.

Comment: Thanks.  In the end I just ended up writing my own code to do the job.  However, it was your answer that put me on the right track so I am accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

[www.dexie.org](http://www.dexie.org)

Minimalistic indexedDB library.

Comment: I wrote my own code to handle all IndexDB stuff a while ago.  Nevertheless dexie looks interesting so +1 for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this jQuery plugin - [jQuery Plugin for indexedDB](https://github.com/axemclion/jquery-indexeddb) It gives you the basic functions like objectStore.count() and objectStore.clear(). Here is the link to Documentation - [Docs](https://github.com/axemclion/jquery-indexeddb/blob/gh-pages/docs/README.md)